# Importing a .csv with a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I've trying to import data from a .csv into an Excel sheet, that's why I've created a command button that by means of the macro that I paste below, it is suppose to let the user select a file. Then it splits its values in range 1...101 into column F and values in range 102...202 into column G.

```
Sub Botón3_Haga_clic_en()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
            .Filters.Clear
            .Title = "Selecciona un archivo .csv"
            .Filters.Add "CSV", "*.csv", 1
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
        Dim sFile As String
        If .Show = True Then
            sFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    If sFile <> "" Then
        Open sFile For Input As #1
            row_number = 0
            Do Until EOF(1)
                Line Input #1, LineFromFile
                LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
                Application.Range("FiguresRange").Cells(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(1)
                'Application.Range("FiguresRange").Cells(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(2)
                row_number = row_number + 1
            Loop
        Close #1
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue with this code is that I get `error '9': sub index out of the range`.

**Note 1**: I've created this code watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9YkM8WvBwI.
**Note 2**: Below is an image of how the sheet looks like in Excel.
[image]

Comment: What does `Debug.Print UBound(LineItems)` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: Where am I suppose to paste that line? Inside the code? Sorry, I'm pretty new in VBA

Comment: Yes, after `LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")`. Then use Ctrl+G to open the Immediate Window.

Comment: It opens the immediate window but it does not show anything

Comment: You have to actually run the code so that `Debug.Print UBound(LineItems)` prints the output.

Comment: I get '0' as an output, and highlights the line which contains 'Application.Range("FiguresRange").Cells(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(1)' in yellow.

Comment: `Split` returns a zero-based array, so the first element is `LineItems(0)`. With the data you selected, there is no second element, so `LineItems(1)` is invalid.

Comment: I see. The code was not doing what I thought it was doing...